Dojo parser : new Function() throws error when CSP with unsafe-eval is disallowed
We are using Dojo v1.17.3 with Content Security Policy (unsafe-eval is disallowed.
Below line gives parser error when onclick is defined.
<div data-dojo-type='dijit.MenuItem' class='tooltip'  id='tooltipID' disabled='true' name='tooltip' onClick='myFunction()'></div> 

Without onclick, above line works fine.
Error details:

error EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed



Rewrite as discussed here: https://web.dev/articles/csp#unsafe-eval
Otherwise you might have implement in a different way, replace the code or accept 'unsafe-eval'.
You should also move away from using event attributes (such as onClick) as they require 'unsafe-inline' or 'unsafe-hashes'.
